# How to repair a cloth item in Divinity: Original Sin EE?

Tags: divinity-original-sin

Normal armor and weapons can be combined with the repair hammer but this is not the case for cloth items like leather armor or head caps.

Comment: Are you on pc? If yes right click on the helmet and choose repair. It will automatically find the appropriate tool

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have 1 point in blacksmithing and possess a repair hammer, anyone linked to the character with those two things can repair *any* item of theirs, armor, weapons etc.

There isn't a separate item or skill to repair differently named/style items or apparel.